# "Verify that the file exists and that you can access it" error on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation

I tried to find the solution to this online but after hours of no progress, I decided to ask here.

I have an installer for a driver. The installer starts but it stops midway giving me the error (for multiple files):

> "Error reading: [filename]. Verify that the file exists and that you can access it."

**What I tried:**

I go to the directory within the installer's folder and find the file exists.  Usually this problem is with `.msi` files but this time, it was with multiple files types (`.exe`, `.dll`, `.cat`, `.inf`, and `.sys`). A̶l̶s̶o̶,̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶I̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶u̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶.̶e̶x̶e̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶d̶i̶v̶i̶d̶u̶a̶l̶l̶y̶,̶ ̶I̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶m̶p̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶I̶ ̶a̶m̶ ̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶u̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶m̶.̶

I also checked my permissions and I have full control for `SYSTEM`.

What can be the issue here? I'm running Windows 7 on a Macbook if it matters.
And [this](http://www.insigniaproducts.com/products/computer-speakers-accessories/NS-PU98505.html) is the link to the driver download.

**Update:** I reinstalled Windows in desperation, but still not fixed. Also, when I try to open the install files mentioned above individually, I am now **unable** to. I get the message: "These files can't be opened. Your Internet security settings prevented one or more files from being opened."

I went to Internet Options and lowered my Local Intranet security (and made sure I was allowed to open unsafe files as well) but this still does not solve the issue.  I also want to make a note that initially, I *was* able to run these files individually but the installer would still fail with the same error.

Comment: Perhaps the installer is corrupted?  Can you download it again?

Comment: @bfhd I've tried that a couple of times. I even used to different programs to extract the downloaded zip file. No luck.

Comment: The quick setup guide at http://www.insigniaproducts.com/cms/documents/qsg/NS-PU98505_NS-PU98505-C_QSG_EN.pdf recommends "Shut down your firewall in case your anti-virus program is preventing
the installation of the driver software."

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking the driver package, and then run as administrator?

Comment: @DavidPostill Tried that, didn't work (but thanks for reminding me, I forgot to turn my firewall back on, oops).

Comment: @Hitsugaya198 Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems you're running into.

## Internet security settings

When you download a file from the Internet, most browsers place a tag on it that says it might not be trustworthy. The Windows ZIP extractor replicates that tag to all files extracted from an untrusted ZIP. Open the properties of the ZIP file you downloaded, then click the **Unblock** button (near the bottom) to remove the tag. Re-extracting the ZIP now that it's trusted should remove the warning when running the files manually.

## Path length limitations

Lots of things in the Windows API will break on paths that are longer than [`MAX_PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1880321/2825369), which is defined as 260 characters. That ZIP file, when expanded, produces some perversely long paths, especially if you have a long username and extract it to your Downloads folder. (It hits exactly 260 for me.) I suggest moving the contents of the

```
Windows\Win7\AX88772B_Win7For32-bit64-bitx86CPUplatformWHQLcertified\AX88772B_Win7_v5.x.7.0_Drivers_Setup_v1.0.4.0
```

directory tree to a new folder with a path that isn't so obscenely long, then running `setup.exe`.

Comment: Moving the files to a shorter path worked! I can award the bounty in 5 hours.

Answer (score 3):

I found that I had changed the default "download" folder location to my D: drive rather than the system C: drive.  Therefore, my permission for the "D:\Download" folder did not have the necessary permissions to execute the .msi file.
I did these steps described:
Right click the folder and to go to folder properties, navigate to security tab, edit the security settings and add "SYSTEM" (no quotes) and click check users button.

After adding system to the download folder, the msi file opened with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The installation file was on a shared google drive folder, If I tryied to install from that location I would get:

"Error reading: [filename]. Verify that the file exists and that you can access it."

I moved the installation files to an other location on my HD, and installation was successful.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means that the SYSTEM user is not able to execute the file (a .msi installer) in that folder.

Right click the folder and to go to folder properties, navigate to security tab, edit the security settings and add SYSTEM user with full permission.

Comment: The question says  that SYSTEM has full control.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Windows 10. It turned out that when extracting, windows copies the content to a folder in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\archivename` but it did not copy all the files! Moving the other files manually to this folder solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is if you have an installer in downloads folder copy it on desktop and then run it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Win7.
If you have extracted setup files in its current path, try to move it to another directory or try to extract it to another path. Then try again. It helped me!

Answer (score -3):

I think you should try installing it manually...Most drivers doesn't install automatically because it is downloaded from the Internet..Anyway if your driver is already installed,and you are trying to update it...Open the device manager and right click on it,then click update driver software,click have disk and locate the .inf file and it should work.

Comment: Saying "most drivers doesn't install automatically because it is downloaded from the Internet" is incorrect.